# runing node.js in production gets wrong

Tags: node.js

I am deploying the node.js server on the aws server, and I followed a [tutorial](http://www.hacksparrow.com/running-express-js-in-production-mode.html) , but it doesn't work as expected.

In the node.js app, I do like this.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'){
   console.log('on production env');
}else if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development'){
   console.log('on development env');
}else {
   console.log('there is nothing about it'.yellow,   process.env.NODE_ENV,process.env);
}

app.configure('development',function(){
    console.log('app on development'.yellow);
});

app.configure('production',function(){
    console.log('app on production'.yellow);
});
```

and before running my node.js app, I export the environment parameter, and it is production when do the echo command.

```
$ export NODE_ENV=production
$ echo $NODE_ENV // output is production
```

and at last, I run the app, but `process.env.NODE_ENV` is **undefined**, and app will always redirect to 'development'

```
app.configure('development',function(){
    console.log('app on development'.yellow);
});
```

what is the problem?

Comment: you can do console.log(process.env) to see everything that is there @ runtime.  might help debug

Comment: Which user runs your node process? Try `$ NODE_ENV=production node your-js.js` and check if that works

Comment: as you suggested, I have tried to debug, it showed the trouble as mentioned, but when I tried Chris's approach, it works